# Blender's pre installed addons don't appear and can't install new ones

Tags: add-on

I've been trying unsuccessfully to install an add-on. Then I noticed that even the add-ons Blender came with don't appear.

They're in the add-ons Blender folder but then when I check for them in *Edit - Preferences - Add-ons*, none of them are there, including the new one I'm trying to add.

In the screen shot I narrowed the search to "mesh" but of course I also searched in "ALL" before. I have a feeling there's some problem with that whole folder.

The circled addon is the one I'm trying to install and the rest were there already, I assume they're the pre installed ones

[image: the circled addon is the one I'm trying to install and the rest were there already, I assume they're the pre installed ones]

Comment: Hello, did you download blender from the official website ?

Comment: Check if Blender prints any error messages to the console / to the info area in the scripting workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Please uncheck "Enabled Add-ons Only"

Comment: yes, I did that... still nothing. I also tries to uninstall and install Blender but it's not fixing the problem. Can't find this issue anywhere in google as well.